# Cannot Run manage.py runserver without failure

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I'm using the pre-packaged, default python light-weight server on a local box to run my application, but it fails to properly run the server - when I run `python manage.py runserver`

I get the following output.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 263, in fetch_command
    app_name = get_commands()[subcommand]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 109, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 134, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'myapp.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/greenlet.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyTrash_thread_deposit_object
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/greenlet.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/greenlet.so
```

**`manage.py` contains:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I've also tried running:

```
>>> import sys
>>> for path in sys.path: print path
```

and this throws a `Segmentation fault: 11` in OSX's terminal

I've verified the path to `myapp.settings` is included on the python path in eclipse->pydev.

Anyone?

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like greenlet is not installed properly. This could be helpful https://github.com/python-greenlet/greenlet/issues/25

Comment: Its mentioning that "Please regenerate your virtualenvs" how can I regenerate my virtualenv?